# Dynamic column and values in react table

Tags: reactjs

```
response : {initial_data: [{
 "Did I see this plant in 2016?"=>"No",
 "Did I see this plant in 2017?"=>"Yes",
 "How Many?"=>1,
 "User Data 4"=>"x",
 "User Data 5"=>nil,
 "Did I see this plant in 2022?"=>"No",
 "Name"=>"Abronia alpina"},
 {"Did I see this plant in 2016?"=>"No",
 "Did I see this plant in 2017?"=>"No",
 "How Many?"=>11,
 "User Data 4"=>"x",
 "User Data 5"=>nil,
 "Did I see this plant in 2022?"=>"Yes",
 "Name"=>"Abronia alpina1"}]
}
```

Based on above response I am executing below code to print the header and there values dynamically.

> ```
> const CUSTOM_COLUMNS = (Object.keys(props.initial_data[0].map((item, index) =>
>                             [{
>                               id: 'user_data',
>                               Header: item,
>                               headerClassName: 'family-header',
>                               accessor: item,
>                               className: 'centered capitalize',
>                               show: true
>                             }][0]
>                           ));
>
> const columns = [
>   ...CUSTOM_COLUMNS,
>   {
>     Header: 'Actions',
>     accessor: 'id',
>     show: true,
>     className: 'centered',
>     Cell: (props) => (
>       <span className="label label-danger link" onClick={this.deletePlant.bind(this, props.value)}>
>         <i className="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
>       </span>
>     )
>   }
> ];
> ```

I able to correctly print the header dynamically, but my values are not coming dynamically and it's displaying my last hash key values in each column.

My header should be :

```
["Did I see this plant in 2016?", "Did I see this plant in 2017?", "How Many?", "User Data 4", "User Data 5", "Did I see this plant in 2022?", "Name"]
```

and row values should be:

```
Row1 : ["No", "Yes", 1, "x", "", "No", "Abronia alpina"]
Row1 : ["No", "No", 11, "x", "", "Yes", "Abronia alpina1"]
```

Can you please help me to get it dynamically, or let me know what I am doing wrong here. I am new in react so maybe i am missing here so please correct me.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table), to render the table, I think your logic of creating columns is wrong. It should be something like this.

```
const columns = Object.keys(response.initial_data[0]).map((key, id)=>{
  return {
    Header: key,
    accessor: key
  }
})
```

I have tried to create a snippet with your data. Let me know if this helps.

```js
const ReactTable = window.ReactTable.default

const response = {
  initial_data: [
   {
     "Did I see this plant in 2016?":"No",
     "Did I see this plant in 2017?":"Yes",
     "How Many?":1,
     "User Data 4":"x",
     "User Data 5":"",
     "Did I see this plant in 2022?":"No",
     "Name":"Abronia alpina"
   },
   {
     "Did I see this plant in 2016?":"No",
     "Did I see this plant in 2017?":"No",
     "How Many?":11,
     "User Data 4":"x",
     "User Data 5":"",
     "Did I see this plant in 2022?":"Yes",
     "Name":"Abronia alpina1"
   }]
}

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const data = response.initial_data

    const columns = Object.keys(response.initial_data[0]).map((key, id)=>{
      return {
        Header: key,
        accessor: key
      }
    })

    return <ReactTable
      data = { data }
      columns = { columns }
    />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.7.6/react-table.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.7.6/react-table.css"></link>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 14):

With [`React-Table`](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme) you header must have a accessor and your data must be mapped with accessor as the key

You would create your columns like

```
  getColumns() {
    return Object.keys(data.initial_data[0]).map(key => {
      return {
        Header: key,
        accessor: key
      };
    });
  }
```

and you Table can then look like

```
class App extends React.Component {
  getColumns() {
    return Object.keys(data.initial_data[0]).map(key => {
      return {
        Header: key,
        accessor: key
      };
    });
  }
  render() {
    const columns = this.getColumns();
    console.log(data.initial_data);
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data.initial_data}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />
        <Tips />
        <Logo />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

According to documentation:

```
accessor: 'propertyName', // or Accessor eg. (row) => row.propertyName
```

> `Accessors` are functions that return the value to populate the row's
>   value for the column. This lets the render function not have to worry
>   about accessing the correct data, the value is automatically populated
>   in it's props.
>
> If a string or array is passed the default accessor is used. The
>   default accessor will parse the input into an array and recursively
>   flatten it. Any values that contain a dot (.) will be split. Any
>   values that contain bracket ([]) will be split. This array is then
>   used as the path to the value to return.

**[Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jv1jk42mlw)**